# Checking if user has inputted .## cents

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am trying to figure out how to check if .00 cents were entered by user with this regular expression:

^\d+(.\d{2})?$

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot `.` is an special character that matches any character (except newline), so you have to escape it:

```
^\d+(\.\d{2})?$
     ^---- Here
```

Btw, if you want just to match and not grab content into the capturing group you can use:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/wI8nY5/2)**

Comment: thanks for your response. 

I want the regular expression to match 

1.00 - should match

Where as .00 (by itself) won't and 1 (by itself) won't ether

Comment: if you want to match 1.00 then just remove the `?`. You can have `^\d+\.\d{2}$`

Comment: i have this regex in a validator @Fede and when i type in 1.00 the regex won't pick up that the user entered 1.00 it should fire. 

instead it's firing for 1 or .00 I want the opposite.

Comment: when the user inputs 1.00 i want the regex to not match I guess?

Comment: I want the opposite of that expression to happen! Please help thanks!

Comment: @Indianaadminstopstuck I'm not sure what you want since your question asks for a different problem than your comment. If I understand your comment you can use this regex `^(?:\d+\.?|\.?\d{2})$` [demo](http://regex101.com/r/wI8nY5/5)